# migration AWS Lambda to graviton - property Architectures not defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want use graviton with my AWS Lambda (Python). So I read AWS official docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html

```
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  Architectures: List
```

My AWS Lambda contains a Layer, So I read AWS official docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-layerversion.html

```
Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
Properties:
  CompatibleArchitectures: List
```

**My cloudFormation:**

```
MyBulkUploadFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${Project}-my-bulk-upload-${Environment}
      Role: !Sub ${RoleLambda}
      CodeUri: lambdas/bulk_upload/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Layers:
        - !Ref MyDataLayer
      Runtime: python3.9
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      VpcConfig: # For accessing RDS instance
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref privateLambdaSubnet1
          - !Ref privateLambdaSubnet2
      Environment:
        Variables:
          RDS_HOST: !GetAtt DatabasePrimaryInstance.Endpoint.Address
          RDS_USERNAME: AWS::NoValue
          RDS_PASSWORD: AWS::NoValue
          RDS_SECRET_NAME: !Ref DatabasePrimaryInstanceSecret
          RDS_DB_NAME: !Ref RDSName
          BULK_UPLOAD_S3_BUCKET: !Sub ${Project}-my-bulk-upload-${Environment}
      Events:
        UploadFile:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref MyBulkUploadS3
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*


  MyDataLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: !Sub ${Project}-my-data-layer-${Environment}
      Description: Common
      ContentUri: lambdas/my_common/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.9
      CompatibleArchitectures:
        - arm64
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: makefile
```

**Error console output:**

```
samcli.commands.validate.lib.exceptions.InvalidSamDocumentException: [InvalidResourceException('MyBulkUploadFunction', 'property Architectures not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function'), InvalidResourceException('MyDataLayer', 'property CompatibleArchitectures not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion')] ('MyBulkUploadFunction', 'property Architectures not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function') ('MyDataLayer', 'property CompatibleArchitectures not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda on graviton need AWS SAM CLI version greater than or equal to 1.33.0

```
sam --version
SAM CLI, version 1.33.0
```